# Recommendation for a source on particle detectors

Tags: resource-recommendations, particle-detectors, accelerator-physics, particle-accelerators

I am looking for suggestions on a particle detectors book. I have average knowledge in high energy physics and nuclear physics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are a plenty of books. But I'm giving here very few of those, which I had come across and more or less read in different parts of my life:

1. **Particle Detection with Drift Chambers by B. H. Wiik:**

This book you may use as a comprehensive guide to the theory and practical aspects of drift chamber particle detectors. It covers the basic principles of drift chambers, including their construction, operation, and performance. The book is well-illustrated and provides detailed descriptions of the components and techniques used in drift chamber particle detection. The book is aimed at advanced students and researchers in physics, and assumes some prior knowledge of particle physics and detector technology.

2. **Particle Detection with Stress-Gradient Chambers by R. Santonico and R. Cardarelli:**

This book provides a thorough introduction to the design, construction, and operation of stress-gradient chambers. The authors cover the fundamental principles of these detectors and provide detailed descriptions of the various components, including the electrodes and the readout system. The book also includes a discussion of the performance of these detectors and the challenges they face in particle detection. The book is intended for advanced students and researchers in physics and requires some prior knowledge of particle physics and detector technology.

3. **Semiconductor Detector Systems by A. S. Balakin:**

This book provides a comprehensive introduction to the design, construction, and operation of semiconductor detectors. The author covers the basic principles of semiconductor physics and the properties of semiconductor materials that make them useful for particle detection. The book also provides detailed descriptions of the various components used in semiconductor detectors, including the readout system, and covers the performance and limitations of these detectors. The book is intended for advanced students and researchers in physics and requires some prior knowledge of particle physics and semiconductor technology.

4. **Gas Detectors for Particles and Radiation edited by E. A. Knippenberg:**

This book is a comprehensive collection of articles on the various types of gas detectors used in particle and radiation detection. The authors provide detailed descriptions of the design, construction, and operation of each type of detector, including proportional counters, drift chambers, and time projection chambers. The book also covers the performance and limitations of these detectors and their applications in particle and radiation physics. The book is intended for advanced students and researchers in physics and requires some prior knowledge of particle physics and detector technology.

5. **Particle Detection with Liquid Argon Time Projection Chambers edited by C. Rubbia and P. Cennini:**

This book is a collection of articles on the design, construction, and operation of liquid argon time projection chambers. The authors provide a comprehensive overview of these detectors, including their basic principles, components, and techniques. The book also covers the performance and limitations of these detectors and their applications in particle physics. The book is intended for advanced students and researchers in physics and requires some prior knowledge of particle physics and detector technology.

6. **Particle Detection with Drift Chambers by T. Ypsilantis:**

This book provides a comprehensive introduction to the design, construction, and operation of drift chambers, a type of particle detector. The author covers the basic principles of drift chamber technology, including the design of the electrodes and the operation of the drift chamber, and provides a detailed overview of the performance and limitations of these detectors. The book also includes a discussion of the challenges faced in drift chamber technology and the advances that have been made in this field. The book is intended for advanced students and researchers in physics and requires some prior knowledge of particle physics and detector technology.

7. **Particle Detectors by C. Rubbia and A. Santoni:**

This book provides a comprehensive introduction to the design, construction, and operation of particle detectors. The authors cover the basic principles of particle detection, including the various types of detectors and their components, and provide a detailed overview of the performance and limitations of these detectors. The book also includes a discussion of the challenges faced in particle detection and the advances that have been made in this field. The book is intended for advanced students and researchers in physics and requires some prior knowledge of particle physics and detector technology.

8. **Fundamentals of Detectors for Particle Radiation by E.A. Knippenberg:**

This book provides a comprehensive introduction to the principles and techniques of particle radiation detection. The author covers the basic concepts of particle detection, including the various types of detectors and their components, and provides a detailed overview of the performance and limitations of these detectors. The book also includes a discussion of the various techniques used in particle detection, such as pulse processing, signal analysis, and data acquisition. The book is intended for advanced students and researchers in physics and requires some prior knowledge of particle physics and detector technology.

9. **The Physics of Particle Detectors by Danilo Enrico Giomi:**

This book provides a comprehensive introduction to the physics of particle detectors. The author covers the basic concepts of particle detection, including the various types of detectors and their components, and provides a detailed overview of the performance and limitations of these detectors. The book also includes a discussion of the various techniques used in particle detection, such as pulse processing, signal analysis, and data acquisition. The book is intended for advanced students and researchers in physics and requires some prior knowledge of particle physics and detector technology.

10. **Particle Detectors and Their Applications edited by C.M. Bhat and J.T. Rouse:**

This book is a collection of articles on the various types of particle detectors and their applications. The authors provide a comprehensive overview of the various types of detectors, including scintillation detectors, solid-state detectors, and gas detectors, and provide detailed descriptions of the design, construction, and operation of these detectors. The book also covers the performance and limitations of these detectors and their applications in particle physics, nuclear physics, and medical physics. The book is intended for advanced students and researchers in physics and requires some prior knowledge of particle physics and detector technology.

11. **Calorimeter Systems for Particle Physics by P. Sievers:**

This book provides a comprehensive introduction to the design, construction, and operation of calorimeters, a type of particle detector. The author covers the basic principles of calorimeter technology, including the design of the detector elements and the operation of the calorimeter, and provides a detailed overview of the performance and limitations of these detectors. The book also includes a discussion of the challenges faced in calorimeter technology and the advances that have been made in this field. The book is intended for advanced students and researchers in physics and requires some prior knowledge of particle physics and detector technology.

Besides these, there is another famous, as well as fascinating book,

- **Particle Detection with Drift Chambers** *by Luigi Rolandi, Werner Riegler and Walter Blum*.